# How to get file content on O365 sharepoint folder using graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

Using Python and the adal and requests packages I'm attempting to use the MS graph API to find files on sharepoint (when providing a sharepoint site name, folder name where the file is expected to be, and name of file.

Using various calls I can manage to do the following

1. Get an authentication token (using user auth to an app which has full permission to use users credentials and do all read/write on files being accessed)
2. establish a valid session
3. search sites and obtain details on my current site

```
microsoft_info = SESSION.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=nameOfSite')
```

4. Obtain drive information associated with the site

```
for site in microsoft_info['value']:
    if site['displayName'] == siteDisplayNameInput:
        siteId = site['id']
        drives = SESSION.get("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/"+siteId+"/drives")
        drives = drives.json()
```

5. Obtain file information from drive of interest

```
        for drive in drives['value']:
            if(drive['name']) == folderNameInput:
                driveId = drive['id']
                files = SESSION.get("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/" + driveId +"/root/search(q='')")
                files = files.json()
```

And then at point 6 everything falls apart and I get 404 errors returned saying that resource is not found - despite using the identifiers provided by the API which are clearly indicating the presence of a resource.

```
                    if file['name'] == 'Pipeline Pilot Forms.pptx':
                        print("List of properties on file")
                        for x in file:
                            print(x+" "+str(file[x]))
                        fileId = file['id']
                        print(fileId)
callToDLFile = SESSION.get("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/"+driveId+"/items/"+fileId+"/content"
```

appears to be the code that should work for this (indentation appears to have failed copying things into this, but it is all good) but it returns 404 errors - any help would be greatly appreciated on this, I don't see (in a reasonably lengthy search) anything which matches this issue exactly out there.

Comment: What do you get if you try this call using Graph Explorer? Also, have you tried requesting the metadata only (i.e. not requesting `/content`)?

Comment: Does the same for metadata - the drive will also state that it has 5 children but the /children call on the drive returns value :[] - a colleague running it with their user and another app returns the expected data - however both apps appear to be identical in setup. I’d be interested to know what things might be going on to make this fail (I am the sharepoint site owner, so technically it shouldn’t be a permissions thing)

Comment: Solution to this issue

Applications require that users grant permissions (it is insufficient to simply say that an app has those permissions) - in the App registrations page this option *doesnt appear to be available* however in the App registrations(legacy) page this option is available in the Required Permissions section.

I had an initial setup where I must have granted permissions to do basic authentication, but later added API permissions for file read/write through the non legacy page - without ever granting these permissions. The permission grant fixed the issue.